# Populating a combobox with enum array

Tags: c#, combobox, populate

I have this array

```
enum Currencies {AUS, CYN, DKK, EUO, INR, NZS, AID, UKP, USA, VND};
```

and i'm trying to populate a combo box in a form with them.

```
        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox2. = 
    }
```

I can't get past this, how do I populate the combobox with the array Currencies?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this,

```
  comboBox2.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Currencies));
```